# What are the words for the two parts of a round trip?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there two single words to differentiate the two parts of a round trip?

If a single word does not exists, what is the shortest yet currently used locution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a word for "part of a route"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32089/is-there-a-word-for-part-of-a-route)

Comment: Also, please don't thank us in the question; I will ruthlessly delete any Thankses at the end!

Comment: There and Back Again :)

Comment: @Robusto I thought it was a duplicate at first, and then realized many possible answers are not part of that other question!

Comment: @Robusto (or moderator): If this question ends up being closed as duplicate, can the answers below be migrated to the duplicate?

Comment: @Robusto I saw that question, but I'm referring to physical travel, and specifically to two logically separated movements. Yes, these two parts may be called legs or segments, but how do I distinguish the one which leads me from my home to, let's say, Honolulu, and the one which brings me back?

Comment: +1 this is exactly the question I was looking for. I needed to differentiate the two multi-leg portions of a round trip.

Comment: I was searching for something very similar to this. I'm on the fence about if it answers your question or not, but I eventually found *depart / departure / departing* and *return* to be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to differentiate, they would be the *outward* leg and the *return* leg.

Answer (score 16):

> **outbound** |ˈaʊtˈˌbaʊnd| (adjective & adverb)
>   traveling away from a particular place, esp. on the first leg of a round trip: *an outbound flight*, *flying outbound*.
>
> **inbound** |ˈɪnˈˌbaʊnd| (adjective & adverb)
>   traveling toward a particular place, esp. when returning to the original point of departure: *inbound traffic*, *we have three enemy planes inbound on bearing two ninety*.

*Return* is also adequate for the latter, as indicated by JeffSahol.

Comment: +1 I like the symmetry in these. I prefer them to _outward_ and _return_.

Answer (score 4):

Parts of trips are *legs*, but that can also mean a trip where you had a layover (two legs in the same direction).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of additional options of interest here...

Though people do use the word *legs*, I think the more common thing in practice is actually *going there* and *coming back* as adverbial phrases (e.g., "Coming back, we fly Delta"); or you can simply talk about the *outbound trip* or *outbound portion of the trip* and the *return portion of the trip* ("The return portion of the trip is 6 hours long".)

You can even say "My/The return flight is 6 hours long."  Since a return trip requires multiple flights, this is unlikely to cause ambiguity.

Finally, somebody mentioned the potential ambiguity of *legs*.  Some of this ambiguity can be resolved by using *segments* instead (legs being made up of segments).  This is a word that the airline folks tend to use a lot.